# SSIS\C# file access - manual access is possible, but from code errers are thrown

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows, ssis, active-directory

I have encountered following issue when I tried to create file on shared (remote) folder:

When I am trying to create, modify, or delete file on shared folder it works just fine, but when I am trying to do the same from SQL Server JOB it fails miserably.

Job is configured to fire SSIS package which is trying to write report file to shared resource. Job owner is set to the same account that I checked to have proper access permissions. Moreover there is no proxy account set for SSIS step. Job owner is also a sysadmin.

As far as i was able to check access to resource to this user is granted by a membership in active directory group.

I recieved following errors from SSIS package:
Flat File Destination:

```
The file name property is not valid. The file name is a device or contains invalid characters.
```

Scrip Task (I made it to check if it is possible to create file from C# code):

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '\\[Some_Directory]\[File_Name]_YYYY-MM-DD-HH-mm-ss.txt' is denied.
```

I have to say I'm at a loss... It really looks like access violation problem, yet manually accessing and modyfing resource works just fine.

Do You have any suggestions?

Comment: What account is SSIS running as? Does that account have access to write the file?  Or maybe its sql server agent thats running the package that doent have access.  I cant remember which one actualy runs the job.

Comment: SSIS package is run by job owner (which also have sysadmin role on this instance of SQL Server). I have confirmed that this user can read and write to destination (my coworker impersonated this user and created new file in shared folder manually).

Comment: Package runs via SQL Agent, fails with access violation. Coworker impersonates the account and runs package ?via command line? and it works?

Comment: Coworker logged to system using account that SQL Agent is run on. Then he tried (and succeeded) in creating/deleting/modyfying file on share.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find a root cause of problem described above, but I've managed to put together valid, and simple, workaround. JOB was reconfigured as follows:

- JOB owner was changed to non sysadmin account (regardless of the fact, that domain account agent service was running on **should** have access to resource).
- SSIS package step had its proxy set to another non-administrative account, that was granted full access to resource

As I've written above It was not possible with my access rights to get to the cause of this problem. With 95% probability I suspect problems with Active Directory configuration or other configuration-related problem.